# The recipient isn't associated with any device React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to send Push Notification from POSTMAN to my RN app using EXPO. I ended up with below error:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "error",
        "message": "The recipient \"ExponentPushToken[OrxoEFOL4iLBfbNDSTUskn]\" isn't associated with any device",
        "details": {
            "error": "DeviceNotRegistered"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody come up to help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Since the device is not registered I would suspect its a permission issue.

If you are on Android push notifications should be enabled on install.  Were they enabled?

If you are using IOS you will need to ask the user for permissions to use push notifications.  Did you get the permissions correct?

You can import permissions with expo using

```
import { Permissions } from 'expo';
```

With the expo permissions you can check whether or not the permission has been granted and if it hasn't ask the user for the permission.

```
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
  // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
    // install, so this will only ask on iOS
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }
```

This was taken from the Expo docs.  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html

Keep in mind you cannot send push notifications to the standard simulators.  As Expo says below,

> Note: iOS and Android simulators cannot receive push notifications, to test them out you will need to use a real-life device. Additionally, when calling Permissions.askAsync on the simulator, it will resolve immediately with “undetermined” as the status, regardless of whether you choose to allow or not.